# WPF Silverlight DataGrid Binding issue

Tags: wpf, silverlight, datagrid

Greetings,
I have a Market class defined as

```
public class Market  
{    
     int id,              
     string MarketDescription,  
     List<Event> Events,  
     ....  
}
```

and the Event is defined as

```
public class Event
{    
     int eventid,              
     string EventDescription 
     ....  
}
```

I declare

```
private ObservableCollection<Market> _markets;  
ObservableCollection<Market> Markets  
{            
    get { return _markets; }
    set  
    {        
        _markets = value;  
        base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Markets");
    } 
}
```

In my datagrid I define my ItemSource as

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Markets}"
```

to display the data related to the `Markets` collection, e.g. `MarketDescription` (which is displayed nicely. What I want to do is to be able and display all the data related to the Event class within the same datagrid. I tried to create an ObservableCollection of Events (EventCol) and to utilise as follows

```
  <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Event Description" 
                          x:Name="EventDescription" 
                          Binding="{Binding ElementName=EventCol,                         
                          Path=EventDescription}" 
                          CanUserReorder="True" 
                          CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" />
```

Unfortunately the Events list is not displayed.

Could you please direct me to the right place or if you could possibly tell me what am I doing wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the events are also a collection, a simple TextColumn will not cut it. You could display a sub-datagrid by using a `DataGridTemplateColumn` which contains a `DataGrid` whose `ItemsSource` binds to `Events`.